# don't execute piece of code when fullscreenchange

Tags: javascript, promise

```js
 this.visibility = () => {
          document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', function() {
    
          })
                            
         console.log("TEST TEST 123");
     }
    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', this.visibility, false);
```

I want `console.log("TEST TEST 123")` to only execute if `fullscreenchange` didn't happen. It doesn't matter if it went to fullscreen or exitted.`console.log("TEST TEST 123")` shouldn't get executed. The only time it should execute is when fullscreenchange doesn't happen, but there're some parts that cause this `visibilitychange` event.

How would you solve this?

Comment: The `visibilitychange ` event has been trigged?

Comment: "*`fullscreenchange` didn't happen*"- in what timeframe? Your code current installs the event listener as soon as `visibilitychange` is triggered, and then immediately logs.

Comment: the idea is that there are multiple things that might cause `visibilitychange` event to get fired. but i only want `visibilitychange` to get fired for all cases, but fullscreenchange